# Marklogic Java API

Tags: marklogic

Having problem with setting namespaces to DocumentPatchBuilder. My code goes like this

```
XMLDocumentManager documentManager = client.newXMLDocumentManager();
EditableNamespaceContext namespaces = new EditableNamespaceContext();
namespaces.put("ms", "http://org.com/documentspace");
DocumentPatchBuilder patchBuilder = documentManager.newPatchBuilder();
patchBuilder.pathLanguage(DocumentPatchBuilder.PathLanguage.XPATH);
patchBuilder.setNamespaces(namespaces);
patchBuilder.replaceValue(
            "/ms:rootDocument/ms:viewCount",2);
DocumentPatchHandle patchHandle = patchBuilder.build();
documentManager.patch(uri, patchHandle);
```

When i debug the build() i see this xml which doesnt have ms namespace defined and i throws No NameSpace "ms" not defined exception

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<rapi:patch xmlns:rapi="http://marklogic.com/rest-api">
<rapi:replace select="/ms:rootDocument/ms:viewCount">2</rapi:replace>
</rapi:patch>
```

Am i doing something wrong with setting namespaces ??

Comment: What version of the Java Client API are you using? Whether you define any of your own namespaces or not, the root patch element always predefines several prefixes, such as xs and xsi, so what you're showing as the serialized patch does not look complete to me.

Comment: Using java-client-api-3.0.4. I'm defining my own namespace. bu in serialized form i don't see namespace defined  and the default namespaces xs & xsi.

Comment: Your code works fine in my environment, including the generated patch handle containing all expected namespace decls when I dump it out with System.out.println. If you don't think the issue is in your debugging methods or a typo in the namespace between your client and your content, then file an issue on github (https://github.com/marklogic/java-client-api). Also, consider upgrading to the most recent version of 3.0.x, though I don't expect that to be the source of your problem.

Comment: Same code with client PAI version 4.0.1 is working fine for me. Which is the version you are using in your environment. I will file a bug with version.

Comment: I tried the latest versions of both 3 and 4. The latest version of 3 is 3.0.7.

Comment: @SijuSuresh could you test with 3.0.7 before you file a bug?